# What is the Excel equivalent of Matlab's randn function

Tags: microsoft-excel, matlab

The `randn` function of Matlab generates a random number from the standard normal distribution.

What is the equivalent in Excel?

I think the `rand(2)-1` is not the right solution because the random number is uniformly generated, not following the standard normal distribution.

Comment: see: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6241784/produce-random-numbers-with-specific-distribution-with-excel

Answer (score 1):

I think you want:

```
=NORMINV(RAND(),0,1)
```

for a standard normal distribution:

[image]

In the above example **all** the cells in column **A** were filled.  The mean is not exactly zero nor is the S.D. exactly one because they represent the values for this specific sample.